# Linear Transformation confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

While I was studying, I encountered this problem for the first time and got me confused.

Its exact words are as follow,

> > Find matrix *A* that expresses the linear transformation *T* in the form of a matrix transformation *T(X) = AX*.
> >
> > T|x|= |3x+2y|
> >
> > ..|y|_|2y+3x|

The provided examples are a little different than this one. They usually give me 3 sets of matrices or ask me to find the ker(*T*)...

Comment: That's 5 questions now Eddie. It's time you learned [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), especially if you want to ask questions involving column vectors!

Answer (score 2):

Hint :( Just an example )

The matrix of the transformation $$T\begin {pmatrix}x\\y\end {pmatrix} = \begin {pmatrix}3x+2y\\2x+3y\end {pmatrix}$$

is the matrix of coefficients which is $$\begin {pmatrix}3&2\\2&3\end {pmatrix}$$

Comment: I feel I should point out to the asker, the transformation has been changed in this answer (which is why it's more of a hint than an answer).